# How to convert array of objects to serialised?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, serialization

I have an array of object

```
const parameters = [
  {token: '78fe6df3f'},
  {id: '12345'},
  { price: '0 - 9,000,000' },
  { 'area[]': 'Applehead Island' },
  { 'waterfront_type[]': 'Open Water' },
  { property_type_single: 'Single Family/Site Built' },
  { bedrooms: '0 - 5' },
  { baths: '0 - 5' },
  { sqft: '0 - 7500' }
];
```

I want this object to be turned to like below

```
https://www.example.com/properties.php?token=78fe6df3f&id=12345&price=$0%20-%20$3,480,000&area[]=Applehead%20Island&waterfront_type[]=Open%20Water&property_type_single=Single%20Family/Site%20Built&bedrooms=0%20-%205&baths=0%20-%205&sqft=0%20-%207500
```

Please help on how to get this?

Comment: What language is this in? Is this JavaScript?

Comment: That is the array of objects. I need to do fetch calls using that.

Comment: But in which language is this array defined?

Comment: I didn't understand your question, i'm afraid. It is javascript

Comment: thanks, that's what I was looking for

Comment: I want this to use in my react native application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that this is JavaScript, you can use the [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function to URL-encode all of your key-value pairs as you have shown. Simply iterate over the array and concatenate the URL-encoded values:

```js
const parameters = [
  { token: '78fe6df3f'},
  { id: '12345'},
  { price: '0 - 9,000,000' },
  { 'area[]': 'Applehead Island' },
  { 'waterfront_type[]': 'Open Water' },
  { property_type_single: 'Single Family/Site Built' },
  { bedrooms: '0 - 5' },
  { baths: '0 - 5' },
  { sqft: '0 - 7500' }
];

let uri = "https://example.org/properties.php?";
let firstSegment = true;

for(const param of parameters) {
  if(!firstSegment) {
    uri += "&";
    firstSegment = false;
  }
  
  // find out the name of this object's property
  const paramName = Object.keys(param)[0];
  uri += paramName + "=" + encodeURIComponent(param[paramName]);
}

console.log(uri);
```

This can be written more concisely using `map()` and `join()`:

```js
const parameters = [
  { token: '78fe6df3f'},
  { id: '12345'},
  { price: '0 - 9,000,000' },
  { 'area[]': 'Applehead Island' },
  { 'waterfront_type[]': 'Open Water' },
  { property_type_single: 'Single Family/Site Built' },
  { bedrooms: '0 - 5' },
  { baths: '0 - 5' },
  { sqft: '0 - 7500' }
];

let uri = "https://example.org/properties.php?" +
  parameters
    .map(
      param => {
        const name = Object.keys(param)[0];
        return name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(param[name]);
    })
    .join("&");
    
console.log(uri);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could merge all objects into one, go over its properties and merge it to one string:

```
 const result = encodeURIComponent(Object.entries(Object.assign({}, ...parameters)).map(([key, value]) => key + "=" + value).join("&"));
```

Step by step:

```
  [{ k: v }, { k2, v2 }]
```

1) `Object.assign({}, ...parameters)`

```
 { k: v, k2: v2 }
```

2) `Object.entries(...)`

```
 [[k, v], [k2, v2]]
```

3) `.map(([key, value]) => key + "=" + value)`

```
 ["k=v", "k2=v2"]
```

4) `.join("&")`

```
 "k=v&k2=v2"
```

Answer (score 1):

My goal in stack overflow is to explain concepts in a very simplified manner .I have commented in the code , so you will understand every step .

The `${}` are ES6 concepts , if you have never seen them , refer to this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Thanks for challenging me.

So here is my solved code , short and easy .

```
var parameters = [
      {token: '78fe6df3f'},
      {id: '12345'},
      { price: '0 - 9,000,000' },
      { 'area[]': 'Applehead Island' },
      { 'waterfront_type[]': 'Open Water' },
      { property_type_single: 'Single Family/Site Built' },
      { bedrooms: '0 - 5' },
      { baths: '0 - 5' },
      { sqft: '0 - 7500' }
    ];


    //we initialize an empty variable
    var serializedString = '';

    //.map() This loop will loop through the array to pick each object
    parameters.map((i)=>{

      //for-in This loop goes through the key-value inside of each object
      for(var key in i){

        //here we are assigning the stringed values into the variable we declared earlier on
        serializedString +=`${key}=${i[key]}&`;
      }

    });


    //after all this is done , we convert our string into a URL friendly string
    var ourURL_friendlyResult = encodeURIComponent(serializedString);

    //we console it out
    console.log(`https://example.org/properties.php?${ourURL_friendlyResult}`);
```